# How to add custom pop-up for push notification opt-in request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please re-open this post.

I didn't get the expected answer which I was searching for.I have updated the question.

Please take a look.

Currently in my react app, I am showing the browser's native popup message:

[image]

I want to change the popup to look like this:

[image]

I am talking about when you click on here, you get a pop up like this -

[image]

"http://localhost:3000"

I want to change the UI of this.
How can I achieve this?

I don't want it to say 'xyz.com' wants to

Comment: You can't control the style of native browser alerts

Answer (score 1):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the `alert()` functionality.

Or you can use [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) library, it is pretty simple and allows you to style your alerts as you want.

Comment: I am not talking about alerts.
I have edited the question.
Please take a look

Comment: Basically, you need to create a modal popup and display the information including Allow and No Thanks button. If user click on Allow, you can proceed with native popup and if user click on No thanks, you need to do nothing and dont call native popup.